# Magento2 How to generate only configurable products URLs in url_rewrite table?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I have the very large number of products and my url_rewrite table have very large numbers of rows so It was possible to only generate configurable product URLs, not any simple products URLs?

Comment: Your question is quit interesting ..)

Comment: @AmitBera what do you think it can be possible?

Comment: i think ,it can be possible  but i have to check it